# VScode show problems in closed files

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code

I'm using the [ESLint Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) for VScode.

It seems to only show problems (at the problems tab in the bottom panel) at open files, as soon as I close the file, the problem disappear.
There must be a way to show all problems in the workspace including closed files, I use to have that.

I've realized that even with "Show Active Files Only" **toggled off** I still don't see any problems in files that are closed.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve?

Comment: No, I'll post the answer if I'll find it, but I'm not using VScode so much anymore, moved to Intellij

Comment: I added this as an issue/feature request on the vscode git repo but I don't know if it's related more to vscode or eslint https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155172

Comment: In the `vscode` repo, it was decided that the problem actually resides in the `vscode-eslint` plugin. That issue can be tracked [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/1460).

Answer (score 0):

[vscode-eslint](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint) does not work that way and it is not likely that it will be implemented per [dbaeumer's comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/1460#issuecomment-1338912510):

> I am reluctant to implement this due to the performance implications it has.

Implementing this feature is a bad idea. Although it might seem functional for small-scale projects it's not likely that it would work well for larger projects. First, consider how the extension works presently:

1. A file is opened
2. The file is checked with `eslint`
3. Problems are reported
4. Repeat for any other files opened

Then when a file is closed:

1. Remove any problems reported in that file

Everything works performantly and the indicators on the *Problems* tab can be updated quickly.

Next, consider how it would work if it needed to check the entire project with `eslint` and report all problems. For this example, let's consider a project with hundreds of thousands or millions of files totaling gigabytes of data:

1. The project is opened
2. Each file must be iterated to determine if it's appropriate to check with `eslint`
3. Each responsive file must be checked with `eslint`
4. Monitoring must be put into place to watch for writes to any files in the project (creations, deletions, updates) so that they can be checked or re-checked on write

Let's imagine that this has been implemented and a project is opened in VSCode:

- While processing takes place the *Problems* counter is going to go up and up. There's no indication to the user why the problems count is going up despite there being no interaction with files in the project and attempting to view or make sense of the problems tab when there are tens or hundreds of thousands of errors is going to be difficult.
- While processing the project `eslint` is going to be using a lot of CPU time and a lot of memory. Without parallel processing it will take a very long time to complete with no indication to the user of how long that scanning process will take or how much has been completed.
- Any change to the ESLint configuration either by editing `.eslintrc.js` or VSCode's configuration would require re-processing the entire project.

That's just a glimpse at the pitfalls that exist in having whole-project scanning like this. It's not likely to be implemented because of these kinds of implications and because of the complex work that would have to be done to attempt to mitigate them.

Comment: I am using flutter and the extension does exactly that, I have a considerably amount of .dart files and it can check the entire project almost instantaneously.

Comment: @ErnestCollection Flutter doesn't use eslint and so this post doesn't apply for you. Even if it did, it still wouldn't apply because as you've stated you don't have enough files for there to be a performance impact.

Comment: @ahotermh Yes, I know that Flutter doesn't use eslint. But .dart is in some ways similar to typescript. What I meant was, if dart analyzer can do that, probably eslint could use a similar mechanism. As for the files, is hard to tell exactly how many files are you referring to, I think maybe hundred of thousands, my project does not have souch amount, but if I issue a clean command, after 1 second I have 10000+ messages showing in the error panel. I do not know what is considered enough to cause a performance impact, but you always have the option in 1% of the cases to turn the option off.

Comment: @ErnestCollection  Based on your comments I am assuming that you are unfamiliar with eslint internals and how it works on multiple files. As an example, it took me 15 minutes to lint 600k files @ 500 bytes each. Your dart linter works differently.